# Stop the instance triggered by mvn exec:java -PCamelServer

Tags: maven, jetty, apache-camel

I was trying out the example came along with Camel.

I ran it in a remote server using putty.

After I started the server, I closed Putty( Yep !! :( )

Now when I reconnect to putty, am getting a new instance leaving the server.

How to stop that instance, without restarting the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to clarify:

Tomcat is a server which runs a daemon process and can be handled with various scripts. Camel has no runtime component - to run it outside of development usually you need to bundle it with a server (ServiceMix, Tomcat, Jetty, WebSphere or whatnot). In these examples, camel is just run inside a main method, blocking the console (using [this](http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html) feature). If the process somehow still is running when your ssh session ends, you need to kill the process on the machine.

This is rather a unix question more than a camel (or even stack overflow-) question (I assume you run some unix since you connect to it using putty).

But anyway, you need to close the process.

1. Look for the process id (pid) by `ps -ef` and find the row with `mvn exec:java -PCamelServer`
2. Kill it by `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: This is a generic answer to kill any process, which I believed any once can do. What I wanted is a way to stop the instance!!!! considering the Jetty as a server...

I can stop apache tomcat by sh shutdown.sh, form different putty sessions
I want something in that way!

Comment: Also, I clearly mentioned the command, and stated that am trying camel example....

I dnt know how to consider it as unix question!

Comment: Yes you said, but you are assuming this is actually some kind of server running, which is not the case. I updated the answer to explain why there is no server in Camel and that this is a simple OS/Unix question.